# C# LINQ - Comparing a IEnumerable<string> against an anonmyous list?

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, ienumerable

**The basic question**

I have:

- `IEnumerable<string> listA`
- `var listB` (this is an anonymous list generated by a LINQ query)

I want to query a list of objects that contain `listA` to see if they match to `listB`:

```
someObjectList.Where(x => x.listA == listB)
```

The comparison doesn't work - so how do I ensure that both lists are the same type for comparison?

**The detailed question**

I am grouping a larger list into a subset that contains a name and related date(s).

```
var listGroup = from n in list group n by new
   { n.NAME  } into d
   select new
   {
      NAME = d.Key.NAME, listOfDates = from x in d select new
                                     { Date = x.DATE } };
```

I have a object to hold the values for further processing:

```
class SomeObject
{
    public SomeObject()
    {
        _listOfDates = new List<DateTime>();
    }

    private IEnumerable<DateTime> _listOfDates;

    public IEnumerable<DateTime> ListOfDates
    {
        get { return _listOfDates; }
        set { _listOfDates = value; }
    }
 }
```

I am then iterating over the `listGroup` and adding into a generic `List<>` of `SomeObject`:

```
foreach(var item in listGroup)
{
    SomeObject so = new SomeObject();
    // ...do some stuff

    if (some match occurs then add into List<SomeObject>)

}
```

As I iterate through then I want to check the existing `List<SomeOjbect>` for matches:

```
var record = someObjectList.Where(x => x.NAME == item.NAME && 
                                       x.ListOfDates == item.listOfDates)
                           .SingleOrDefault();
```

The problem is that comparing `x.ListOfDates` against `item.listOfDates` doesn't work.

There is no compiler error but I suspect that the returned value lists are different. How to I get the lists to commonize so they can be compared?

**Update #1**

This seems to work to get the `listOfDates` into a similar format:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> tempList = item.listOfDates.Select(x => x.DATE).ToList()
```

Then I followed the 'SequenceEqual' suggestion from @Matt Burland

Answer (score 1):

You can just compare one `IEnumerable<DateTime>` to another `IEnumerable<DateTime>`, you need to compare the *sequence*. Luckily, there's [Enumerable.SequenceEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx) (in both static and extension method flavors) which should work here.

So something like:

```
var record = someObjectList
    .Where(x => x.NAME == item.NAME &&  x.ListOfDates.SequenceEquals(item.listOfDates))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I tried that but get this error:  cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#1>'